# How to disable Firestore Datastore mode for new project and switch to Native Mode

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing a new iOS / Android App for which I need Firestore Native Mode. In my old project I see my Cloud Firestore (in native mode) but in my new project I think I accidentally selected Data-store somewhere, but I didn't add data yet. How can I revert this because I don't want to start a complete new project.

I've read [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore)

Old project:

[image]

Current one:
[image]

After creating 1 entity and removing the same entity, it's not possible anymore to switch to native:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have not added any data to the database, the option to change to Native Mode should appear similar to the be below screenshot, which you can access from the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) directly and *not* from the Firebase Console.

[image: GCP]

There you should be able to change to Native Mode, without creating a new project.

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful. I created an entity and removed it now. But the option does not show anymore. I'm afraid I need to start all over again...

Comment: Same thing happened to me! Is there no way back?

Comment: There is no way back if you have added an entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to Native mode using the following Cloud shell command, but you need to clear all your entities.

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases update --type=firestore-native
```

Take a look at this link https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/firestore-or-datastore?hl=it#changing_between_native_mode_and_datastore_mode